# Force selection options to one line

Tags: html, css, dotcms

```html
<select id="Semester">
  <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
  <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
  <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
</select>
<select id="Year">
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>
<p>
  <input class="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</p>
```

I have this code, which, on StackOverflow is on one line (except for the button). On our CMS, however, each `select` element shows up on a different line like this:

[image]

What can I do to force these all on to one line?

Comment: Try adding this: #Semester, #year, .submit { display:inline-block;}

Comment: Still it would be more easy for us to solve if you provide your web link or create same issue for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: inline-block to all your elements to make them display in one line:

```html
<select id="Semester" style="display: inline-block;">
  <option value="Fall">Fall</option>
  <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
  <option value="Summer">Summer</option>
</select>
<select id="Year" style="display: inline-block;">
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
</select>
<p style="display: inline-block;">
  <input class="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, the best solution is also `display: inline-block`.

However, if you don't have access to the html template files on your CMS, you can try to insert the following on your .css file:

```
#Semester, #Year, #Year + p { display: inline-block;}
```

If it still doesn't work, try adding `!important` just before the last `;`